# Android confusion about ViewModels, ViewModelStoreOwner and state

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to write a simple game, that has some state (player's current score, position of player and other world inhabitants). But not state stored in a DB or externally. It's OK for this to be reset when the MainActivity is recreated.

I realize I'm not meant to keep that state in an Activity.  Presumably not even my MainActivity.

So I can create a ViewModel subclass for it.

Now looking at various onnline examples, it seems I should be getting that ViewModel object by doing something like this in MainActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    GameViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GameViewModel.class);

    model.addObserver( new Observer() {    
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            REDRAW WORLD
        }
    });
}
```

My first problem is that I'm getting a

```
error: no suitable constructor found for ViewModelProvider(MainActivity)
    GameViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GameViewModel.class);
```

The ViewModelProvider can't be created with MainActivity as its ViewModelStoreOwner. But what *should* be the ViewModelStoreOwner in my case? Is this yet another object I have to create somewhere? And in what scope?

The second question is that I want to have user input update the state in my GameViewModel. But the user input handler (onTouchEvent) is being attached to my GameSurfaceView. (A subclass of GLSurfaceView)

But it doesn't look like GameSurfaceView or MainActivity know anything about each other. So how can the GameSurfaceView.onTouchEvent get hold of my GameViewModel which is referenced in the MainActivity?

Is it even meant to? Or is GameViewModel just meant to be a proxy to state stored somewhere else? And, if so, where is that somewhere else?

This is all very confusing.

Comment: It sounds like you're just not using Lifecycle `2.2.0`, which is what adds the `ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner)` constructor. Can you include your build.gradle?

Comment: I'm probably not. But is LifeCycle what I want for something like a simple game?

Comment: Also, will that work down to Android 6? (My lowest target)

Comment: I mean, if you want to save state over configuration changes and use ViewModel, you *are* using Lifecycle. You're just using an older version of it. Lifecycle supports back to Android 4.

Comment: So to the wider question. SHOULD I be using LifeCycle? What other options are there for where I store state for a simple game in a principled way?

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am wondering the same thing.